# Does Groovy @Canonical work with private fields?

Tags: groovy

I keep getting a "Could not find matching constructor" when I use @Canonical annotation with private fields. May I know how I can get the following code to compile and pass the asserts? Thanks :)

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical(includes = ['x','y'])
@groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode(includeFields = true)
class Cell implements Comparable<Cell>{
    private int x
    private int y

    int compareTo(Cell cell){
        x <=> cell.x ?: y <=> cell.y ?: 0
    }
}

Cell cell = new Cell(1,0);
Cell sameCell = new Cell(1,0);
def setOfLiveCells = [] as Set

assert setOfLiveCells.add(cell) // cell is added
assert cell == sameCell // cell equals
assert ! setOfLiveCells.add(sameCell) //should not assert
```

Regards,
John

Comment: I don't think you can. Why not make them public and mark it as Immutable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you **can** do that.

`@Canonical` is a shorthand for `@TupleConstructor` `@ToString` and `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotations with default values. [[code](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/transform/CanonicalASTTransformation.java)] You can specify them by hand, or simply add necessary annotation **before** `Canonical`. `@TupleConstructor` allows you to set fields, via `includeFields` or `include` annotation fields. [[doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html)]

```
@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor(includeFields = true)
@groovy.transform.Canonical
class Cell implements Comparable<Cell>{
    private int x
    private int y

    int compareTo(Cell cell){
        x <=> cell.x ?: y <=> cell.y ?: 0
    }
}

Cell cell = new Cell(1,0);
Cell sameCell = new Cell(1,0);
def setOfLiveCells = [] as Set

assert setOfLiveCells.add(cell) // cell is added
assert cell == sameCell // cell equals
assert ! setOfLiveCells.add(sameCell) //should not assert
```